# How do I find a specific Suite in Azure DevOps Test Plans?

Tags: testing, azure-devops, test-suite, test-plan

I'm using Azure DevOps in my company. After our last migration we have been unable to find specific requirement based suites within our static suites, in a specific test plan.

Our work is organized as such:

```
Test Plan 1 - Static Suite 1 - Static Suite 1.1 - Requirement-based Suite 1.1.1 (nr 111)
                                                - Requirement-based Suite 1.1.2 (nr 222) 
                                                - Requirement-based Suite 1.1.3 (nr 333)
                             - Static Suite 1.2 - Requirement-based Suite 1.2.1 (nr 444)
                                                - Requirement-based Suite 1.2.2 (nr 555)
                                                - Requirement-based Suite 1.2.3 (nr 666)
                             - Static Suite 1.3 - Requirement-based Suite 1.3.1 (nr 777)
                                                - Requirement-based Suite 1.3.2 (nr 888)
                                                - Requirement-based Suite 1.3.3 (nr 999)

            - Static Suite 2 - Static Suite 2.1 - Requirement-based Suite 2.1.1 (nr 111)
                                                - Requirement-based Suite 2.1.2 (nr 222)
                                                - Requirement-based Suite 2.1.3 (nr 333)
                             - Static Suite 2.2 - Requirement-based Suite 2.2.1 (nr 444)
                                                - Requirement-based Suite 2.2.2 (nr 555)
                                                - Requirement-based Suite 2.2.3 (nr 666)
                             - Static Suite 2.3 - Requirement-based Suite 2.3.1 (nr 777)
                                                - Requirement-based Suite 2.3.2 (nr 888)
                                                - Requirement-based Suite 2.3.3 (nr 999)
```

I open the test plan and, with all Suite folders expanded, search for a specific requirement based suite number using CTRL+F.

If I search for "777" I will **only** be shown Requirement-based Suite 1.3.1 (nr 777) when I expected it to find Requirement-based Suite 2.3.1 (nr 777) as well.

I've been searching online for people that have had the same problem but I can't find any reference to this situation anywhere. I am also not the only one within my company to whom this happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the specific requirement based suites with `Ctrl + F`, you need to make sure the list has been loaded/displayed on the page.

For example, I used your list for testing. I clicked the Expand All button.

When I use `Ctrl + F` to search for 111, 222, 333, I can see two results. Because they are displayed on the page. When I use `Ctrl + F` to search for 444, 555,..., 999, the result is the same as you described, only the first one can be found. Because they are not displayed on the page. When I go through the entire list and load/display them on the page, I can find two results.

[image: Azure DevOps Service]

If you don't want to browse the entire content every time, you can use **Filter suit by name**. This will be much more convenient to find the suit you need.

[image: use Filter suit by name in Azure DevOps Service]

Update:

I found that the **Filter suit by name** is only available in Azure DevOps Service. When using Azure DevOps Server, there is no **Filter suit by name**.

[image: Azure DevOps Server]

Comment: Hello! thank you for the help :) I had already attempted with all the suites expanded, but no dice with CTRL+F. I seem to be missing that filter that allows you to filter suite by name

Comment: How do I enable it?

Comment: Hi @Rita, may I know if you are using the Azure DevOps Server? I found that the **Filter suit by name** is only available in Azure DevOps Service.   I have updated the answer with my test screenshot in Azure DevOps Server.